# Predicting ball path - Artificial Intelligence

Tags: math, geometry, artificial-intelligence, box2d

I'm implementing a simple Volleyball game using Box2D in Flash. I need to implement some AI for the CPU player. Let's call him Jack. So Jack needs to predict where's the ball gonna land after it has been hit by John, the human player. I have the following information :

> 1. Initial Linear Velocity (both in x & y direction) of the ball when John
>      hits it.
> 2. The initial position of the ball when John hits it. (x & y coordinate
>      values)
> 3. The value of gravity.
> 4. The value of y position of floor where's the ball's gonna fall.
> 5. The angle at which John hits the ball.
> 6. The ball follow a projectile trajectory.

So Jack needs to predict what would be the position (x value) of the ball when it hits the floor.

I think as the ball follows a projectile trajectory the problem might be seen same as that of  - firing a cannon ball from some known initial position, known initial velocity with fixed gravity and predicting its landing spot. The y value of landing spot is also known. The air resistance is zero.

Is there any kind of mathematical equation which might help to predict the x value of the landing spot? I took a look at some projectile equations but most of them take 'time' as a variable. I need to have a solution that doesn't involve this 'time' variable. Any kind of work-arounds for this problem would also be appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: This isn't so much artificial intelligence as it is exterior ballistics.  I assume the AI comes in later.

Comment: Won't your volleyball game have to simulate the motion of the ball anyway? Why not use the same in the AI part? Actually, I think, it's perfectly fine to precalculate the trajectory once and use it both for time evolution and AI actions. Maybe deteriorate the trajectory for AI by adding some random error on top which allows to tune the quality of Jack's play? Finding the place of first ground contact would then be just a post-processing step on the trajectory.

Comment: @David - Yes you can say that! But most of the books on 'Artificial Intelligence for game development' include this topic of predicting projectile trajectory. :)

@Tilman - Actually sir, I am using Box2D to simulate the ball motion and collision which takes care of all this mathematical stuff. So I can't use it until I actually know the maths behind this. I appreciate your suggestion but I'm afraid I won't be able to precalculate the trajectory motion in the first place if I don't know the equations.

Comment: I don't know Box2D but doesn't it have an interface to extract the trajectory? I guess, you don't need to know the equations if you have a "black-Box2D" which just gives you what you need (the trajectory).

Answer (score 2):

If you have an equation for `z` (i.e. height) in terms of `t`, then you need to solve that for `z = 0` to get the value of `t` when the ball lands.  You can then feed that back into the equations for `x` and `y`.

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit more? I still don't get it. I'm a bit weak at maths. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Anubhav: You say you have equations in terms of `t`?  So you have `x = f1(t)`, `y = f2(t)`, `z = f3(t)` where `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` are some functions?  If that's the case, then we need to find the time `t` when the ball hits the ground; you can do this by solving the `z` equation.  But at this time `t`, there will also be particular values of `x` and `y`, which can be found simply by plugging that number back into the first two equations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve z(x)=0 with this equation:
g is gravity, v0 is initial speed along x axis, a is the angle.

[image: Equation of z with x variable]

When you solve it, it gives the length of the segment joining start point and end point (choose one end point depending on the hit direction).

[image: Resolution]

If you're in 3D, you'll have to do some projections to remove the 3D part of the problem, and keep only two axis.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll implement it and check the results. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's simpler if you solve for landing time as an intermediate step, and use the given velocities instead of messing around with angles.

Answer (score 0):

> Initial Linear Velocity (both in x & y
>   direction) of the ball when John hits
>   it.
>
> The initial position of the ball when
>   John hits it. (x & y coordinate
>   values)
>
> The value of gravity.

And the direction - negative y-direction, of course.  `32.2 ft/sec^2 = 9.8 m/sec^2`, right?

> The value of y position of floor
>   where's the ball's gonna fall.

It'll hit at y = 0 if no other player touches it.

> The angle at which John hits the ball.

I think it'd be better to say something about the force John applies to the ball and for how long.

> The ball follow a projectile
>   trajectory.

No, you have no such thing.  This is what you're trying to solve.

What you have is Newton's law: `F = ma,` where force is the vector of force applied to the ball, m is the mass of the ball, a is the acceleration vector applied to the ball.

The ball is accelerated by gravity in the negative y-direction, of course, but you're forgetting the force vector that the player applies when the ball is struck.

Once you have those you solve two coupled ODEs forward in time.